# Interpretation of `KEY` property of keyboards in udev

Tags: linux, usb, udev, sysfs

In udev/sysfs, keyboards have a `KEY` property. For example, I have an external Mac keyboard that has two "interfaces":

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2.3.2:1.0
ID_INPUT_KEY: 1
ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD: 1
KEY: 10000 0 0 0 1007b00001007 ff9f207ac14057ff ffbeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe

/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2.3.2:1.1
ID_INPUT_KEY: 1
KEY: 3a00000000 e000000000000 0
```

I assume the first is the actual keyboard, and the second is for a special key, maybe the eject key. How can I interpret the `KEY` property? It seems to be some kind of bitmask defining which keys are present. Is it somehow related to scancodes?

Answer (score 1):

That `KEYS` field seems to be a bitmask for the key definitions, e.g. the lowest bit corresponds to the first key. The highest bit corresponds to the last key.

So where do the keys come from?   Try reading `input-event-codes.h` (e.g. from [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/30c2c32d7f703530a6a0c9d2435117a9907d7109/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h#L64)) to get the definitions for the keys. Then you can bit-shift by those values and see whether your mask matches.

It's probably clearer in code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    KEYS = sys.argv[1].replace(" ", "")
else:
    KEYS="3a00000000 e000000000000 0".replace(" ", "")

inputkeys = int(KEYS, 16)

# /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-24/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h


if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    linuxkeys = open(sys.argv[2], "r").read()
else:
    linuxkeys = open("/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-24/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h", "r").read()

# Taken from https://gist.github.com/gsora/45ba7b98d31929e75317908a97488ef1
needle = "#define KEY_RESERVED"
linuxkeys = linuxkeys[linuxkeys.find(needle):]

needle = "#define KEY_MAX"
linuxkeys = linuxkeys[:linuxkeys.find(needle)]


keys = {}
for line in linuxkeys.splitlines():
    goodline = line[8:].split("\t")
    if line.startswith("#define ") and len(goodline)>1:
        key = goodline[0]
        for i in range(1, len(goodline)):
            if goodline[i] == "":
                continue
            else:
                value = goodline[i].rsplit()[0]
                try:
                    v = int(value)
                except ValueError:
                    if value.startswith("0x"):
                        v = int(value[2:], 16)
                    else:
                        v = keys[value]

                keys[key] = v
                break

for k,v in sorted(keys.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]):
    if inputkeys & (1<<v):
        print (k)
```

For your `KEYS` field, I get:

```
KEY_SLASH
KEY_RIGHTSHIFT
KEY_KPASTERISK
KEY_RO
KEY_HIRAGANA
KEY_HENKAN
KEY_KATAKANAHIRAGANA
```